# Get IP of docker container

Tags: java, docker

[I'm using Docker API in Java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) and I'm trying to get the IP from the container using **but it returns null** Btw, the connecting and everything works. It's just this line of code that doesn't

```
 String containerIP = dockerClient.connectToNetworkCmd()
                .withContainerId("2315f8792fdf")
                .getContainerConfig().getIpAddress();
```

If I do `sudo docker inspect 2315f8792fdf`

I have an IP `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.3"`

EDIT: I get this: https://gyazo.com/6373af383de9a64f0cd1c9df1fd71da7

Any help?
`

Comment: Does the command fail even if done against a container that has been running for some time? Also, does it fail when using the full, unabbreviated container ID?